# Restricting user from entering a repeat specific number

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following group of text input fields related to one question:-

```
    <input type="text" name="{{ $answer->id }}" value=""
           style="width:20px; text-align:center"
           maxlength="1" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-5]/g,'');"  />
     <input type="text" name="{{ $answer->id }}" value=""
           style="width:20px; text-align:center"
           maxlength="1" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-5]/g,'');"  />
     <input type="text" name="{{ $answer->id }}" value=""
           style="width:20px; text-align:center"
           maxlength="1" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-5]/g,'');"  />
     <input type="text" name="{{ $answer->id }}" value=""
           style="width:20px; text-align:center"
           maxlength="1" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-5]/g,'');"  />
<input type="text" name="{{ $answer->id }}" value=""
           style="width:20px; text-align:center"
           maxlength="1" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-5]/g,'');"  />
<input type="text" name="{{ $answer->id }}" value=""
           style="width:20px; text-align:center"
           maxlength="1" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-5]/g,'');"  />
<input type="text" name="{{ $answer->id }}" value=""
           style="width:20px; text-align:center"
           maxlength="1" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-5]/g,'');"  />
<input type="text" name="{{ $answer->id }}" value=""
           style="width:20px; text-align:center"
           maxlength="1" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-5]/g,'');"  />
```

As you can see that i already implemented a restriction to not allow inputting an integer > (greater than) 5 .

The above text input is to let user rate the answers by putting a number from 1-5,

I want a JavaScript code  that restrict user from repeating the rating with the number 3 more than 2 times and with number 2 not more than 1 time.

Comment: You have already set `maxlength="1"` so user anyway can't enter any 2 digit number.

Comment: you have 8 inputs, how you want the user to give to each a unique value 0-5?

Comment: Please show us what you tried yourself

Comment: @palaѕн i don't mean restricting user by length, what i want is that user have to rate between different options and rating to be a value between 1 to 5 , i want to restrict user from rating the available options with the value (3) more than 2 times.

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky The question as i mentioned above is let a user rate the available options not ordering them . what i want is that user have to rate between different options and rating to be a value between 1 to 5 , i want to restrict user from rating the available options with the value (3) more than 2 times.

Comment: There are 8 inputs, so one time the ratings will be repeated no matter what.. like 1 for 1st input, 2 for 2nd input... 5 for 5th input, but for 6th input user has to enter something between 1-5.. so ratings will be repeated. At this point your question is not making any sense to me. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @KooiInc i don't have any thing on my mind, but the concept of what of what i want is similar to this : (Some logic that keeps monitoring or listening to a <div> group of input field and checking if user entered a value (3) more than 2 times , it will not allow him. in another way, let define a var "num3" with value = 2 . if user used the number 3 some logic will - the var num3 so the value will be =1, then if he use the number 3 again the var value will be 0 then if that var value is 0 it will not allow him to use the number 3 anymore on those grouped fileds.

Comment: @palaѕн you are totally right, the above code i posted i just an example to reduce the question size, the real number of text input i am using is 16 not 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow:

***1.*** only numbers 1-5

***2.*** max of 1 appearance of value '2'

***3.*** max of 2 appearance of value '3'

Hope it is what you looking for

```js
var inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
function validate(el) {
  var valid = true;
  if(!/[1-5]/.test(el.value)) valid = false;
  if(el.value == '2' && inputs.some(t => t !== el && t.value == '2')) valid = false;
  if(el.value == '3' && inputs.reduce((a, b) => a + (b.value === '3' ? 1 : 0) ,0) >= 3) valid = false;
  if(!valid) el.value = '';
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>q1<input type="text" oninput="validate(this)" maxlength="1"/></label>
<label>q2<input type="text" oninput="validate(this)" maxlength="1"/></label>
<label>q3<input type="text" oninput="validate(this)" maxlength="1"/></label>
<label>q4<input type="text" oninput="validate(this)" maxlength="1"/></label>
<label>q5<input type="text" oninput="validate(this)" maxlength="1"/></label>
<label>q6<input type="text" oninput="validate(this)" maxlength="1"/></label>
<label>q7<input type="text" oninput="validate(this)" maxlength="1"/></label>
<label>q8<input type="text" oninput="validate(this)" maxlength="1"/></label>
```

Comment: I am not able to use the value (2) and value 3 is allowed to used one time only, please confirm .

Comment: I can see it's working very well on your code snippet example, but when i used the above code on my page it's not . please consider that my page contain many other text input fields. is there any code to let the code work under only a specific dev tag

Comment: for example `document.querySelectorAll(.relevant-div input)`

Comment: or `document.querySelectorAll(input[name="inputs-name"])` if they all have the same name (as its look like from your code)

Answer (score -1):

Is this something you're looking for? Use oninput="validate(this)" in the inputs.

```
function validate(elem) {
    elem.value=elem.value.replace(/[^0-5]/g,'');           

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i] == elem) continue;
        if (inputs[i].value == elem.value) count++;
    }
    switch(elem.value) {
        case '3':
        case 3: 
            if (count >= 2) {
                elem.value = '';
                return false;
            }
            break;
        case '2':
        case 2:
            if (count >= 1) {
                elem.value = '';
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
    }
    return true;
}
```